# Separate an object in a array of objects

Tags: arrays, object, key-value

Im consuming data from an API

```
"stats": [
{
  "base_stat": 48,
  "effort": 1,
  "stat": {
    "name": "hp",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/1/"
  }
},
{
  "base_stat": 48,
  "effort": 0,
  "stat": {
    "name": "attack",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/2/"
  }
}]
```

So when i recieve this, im doing =>

```
const selectedStats = stats.reduce(
(acc, stat) => ({ ...acc, [stat.stat.name]: stat.base_stat }),
{} ); 
    // OUTPUT => stats: {
attack: 48
hp: 48 }
```

But now im trying to separate an object in a array of objects, like

```
[{attack: 81}, {hp: 48}, etc]
```

but i don't know how to do it

Sorry if this is a large question but i don't get the solve. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the result of [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) would do it:

```js
const stats = {
  attack: 48,
  hp: 48
};

const data = Object.entries(stats).map(([k, v]) => ({[k]: v}));

console.log(data);
```

You don't need the intermediate `reduce()` though. Since you're starting off with an array, you can do everything in a single `map()` operation:

```js
const stats = [{
  "base_stat": 48,
  "effort": 1,
  "stat": {
    "name": "hp",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/1/"
  }
}, {
  "base_stat": 48,
  "effort": 0,
  "stat": {
    "name": "attack",
    "url": "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/stat/2/"
  }
}];

const data = stats.map(({base_stat, stat: {name}}) => ({[name]: base_stat}));

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Damn, i feel dumb now viewing the solve haha, thanks! :)